Troubleshooting Pivot Table Display Issues: Slicing by related Table in Power BI Model
I have a model with the following relations.

I calculate the following measure.
TEST =
CALCULATE(
   [Conso A Plan Clé], // SUM coming from ‘BDD Index’
    ALLSELECTED('Plans Comptages')
)

When I display this measure in a pivot table sliced by BAT from 'Plans Comptages', everything works fine.

However, in my model, I want to slice it using the BAT table. When I try to do so, the pivot table display is no longer correct. It seems like the slice filter is not being applied, and lines related to other BATs are displayed with no values.
I've attempted to add a KEEPFILTERS('BAT') condition with no success. It's driving me crazy. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
(Pbix file here)


The relationship you have with BAT table, flows through the Plans Comptages table, and you are removing all filters from Plans Comptages.
If you rework your measure this way:
TEST =
CALCULATE(
[Conso A Plan Clé], // SUM coming from ‘BDD Index’
ALLEXCEPT('Plans Comptages'[BAT])
)
If this doesn't work, will you send a sample data from BDD Index, Plans Comptages, and BAT, so I can try something else?

Actually, it only works if I have 'Plans Comptages'[BAT] in my pivot table... Without, i keep having the non desired lines... File link above... Thanks in advance.
